# how to read geolitecity file path from linux server?

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, geoip

My development environment is `windows`, using `JSP,Apache server 5.5`. I developed an application with the help of geolitecity provided by `MaxMind`. I have uploaded `geolitecity.dat` into my server in the same folder of my website(I dont know its the correct procedure, I am doing it first time).And I used

```
String systemPath=new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath();
```

to get the current directory path, so that I can read from it. But I am not getting the full path. am only getting upto `tomcat5.5.3\bin`. Is it possible to read the file with this path? I dont have much knowledge in linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Servlet/JSP:

```
String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/yourfilename.txt");
```

This will give you complete path of given file name.

Note: It will work when you will deploy it in tomcat and run from out side eclipse. As eclipse has its own internal structure when it deploy the web application [if not changed].

Comment: thanks thats was much helpful. I have solved my problem by this.